# Kibana i see Indices and fields but cannot Chart or Visualize

Tags: kibana

I curled the sample bank data to elasticsearch. On Kibana I see under the `Indices` bank and on visualize all the fields (age, balance, etc.) on the *left* but cannot see charts on the *right*. It always says `No Results Found`. On the left I selected `Y-Axis - Agg as Average` and `Field as Balance` and `X-Axis Agg as Terms` and `Field as Age`, all from drop downs. Then I used the `APPLY` action. No error is displayed, but neither is a chart.

What am I doing wrong here? Using curl I can check the elastic search and see that the data exists. No matter what I do, I do not see any logging in the elasticsearch logs under `/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs`.

Comment: I was having the exact same issue, except one of my four indices DOES work... Turns out I was searching in the wrong time period for the rest of my indices. Are you in the right time period? Might say "Last 15 minutes" by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you figured this out or not but I had the exact same problem. I was using a mapping type that did not contain the field I was trying to visualize. Make sure the _type field contains a mapping with the correct indexed fields.

Comment: I deleted the indices and recreated it. It solved the problem, something was wrong with my inserting.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up my initial index patterns, I glossed over specifying the 'Default timestamp' field, and the UI didn't insist on having one. The fix was to delete my index patterns and re-create them them, with the specified timestamp field. Everything snapped into place.